# How to fix font-lock for Java generics?

Tags: emacs

Emacs (even the latest 24.3.1) fails to render Java generics correctly.

```
static<T> void println(T arg) { System.out.println(arg); }
```

In the above example the method name `printf` is not rendered as a function. It is black and not blue.

I think it must be possible to fix this by some better regular expressions. Does anybody know how to do it?

Comment: You have to find the variable that defines font locking for java-mode, and then replace every instance of "static" with "static<[a-zA-Z ,]+>".  That should work, but I'm not familiar with java generics, so you'll have to generalize for other situations where they are applicable.

Comment: It is not that easy. The order of method prefixes is random.

Comment: Does this apply to the <T>? Or does it have to come after a prefix?

Comment: Here is a Java tutorial: http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/introduction-to-java-access-modifiers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this to highlight generics in java correctly:

```
(setq c-recognize-<>-arglists t)
```

Comment: Fine! Seems to work. Do you also know how to get the constructor blue?

Comment: I am sorry, I do not know that, but you might want to go and ask the people one the mailinglist, or search the ML archives for such a question. It seems to me that it should be quite a common request.